# Open copied google slide file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-slides

I'm looking to copy a "template" Google Slides file, then modify text fields in the newly created file. I'm having an issue with opening the copied file. I'm new to Google scripts and found some code that seems it should work, but I'm getting an error. Here is the code and the error:

```
function createDuplicateDocument(sourceId, name) {
    var source = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceId);
    var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER);
    var newFile = source.makeCopy(name, targetFolder);
    return DocumentApp.openById(newFile.getId()); 
}
// Document is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?) (line 35, file "Code") 

var SOURCE_TEMPLATE = "1OUztWdzh..."; // Google Doc id from the document template (Get id from the URL)
var TARGET_FOLDER = "1xsbW_pjZuN..."; //"Sent_Certificates"; // In which Google Drive we toss the target documents
var name = TRAINING_DATE + "_" + TRAINING_TYPE + "_" +TRAINING_USER
var filTxtFile = createDuplicateDocument(SOURCE_TEMPLATE, name);
replaceString(filTxtFile, "TRAINING_USER", TRAINING_USER);
```

As soon as I run the code, I can see the new file in the correct folder, but for some reason, the script can't see it.
I've also tested placing the code of the function inline with my code, but I cant get it to open the copied file. I just get an error stating the file is missing. I've made sure to sign out of all other accounts and even put in a sleep timer to see if it was just executing too fast.

In the end my goal is to fill out a training certificate with the users info from a Google Form.

Why am I getting that error and how to resolve.
Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify if the source document a Google Document or a Google Slides file? You call it a "presentation", which to me implies Google Slides, and that might be the issue.

Comment: can you share the rest of the code so we can see the context please?

Comment: @CameronRoberts and JSmith, I have editied the original question with more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are dealing with a Slides file, you must open it with SlidesApp rather than DocumentApp.  DocumentApp only handles Google Documents, which is why you are getting this error.

```
return SlidesApp.openById(newFile.getId());
```

Comment: Good to know, the error "Document is missing" means Google Doc, not generic document. Thank you!